# How to remove .swp file that is 'outside repository'

Tags: git

Whenever I try to commit code I get a message:

> Found a swap file by the name "/tmp/.commit-message.swp"

I searched SE and found that I could remove it with git rm, eg:

```
git rm /tmp/.commit-message.swp
```

But I get the message:

> fatal: '/tmp/.commit-message.swp' is outside repository

I have only limited experience in Git. Would anyone know how I can get rid of this?

(note: I searched my drive for this file but could not find it)

Comment: Drop `git` and just use `rm /tmp/.commit-message.swp`?

Comment: navigate to tmp than git rm "commit-message.swp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means your `tmp` folder is not inside your git project. You can just remove your file by the usual `rm` command without using git.

Maybe check that you are in the right project, or add this folder to your project first (then remove the file).